# Connect to WLAN swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

Is it possible to connect to `WLAN` using `swift`, in case I receive `WLAN SSID` and `password` from API with my permissions, and before connection I also accept Terms & Conditions. So as a user I totally agree that to happen through a particular app. So I'll search for/or get my local area network by name/WLAN SSID, and connect to it by password but all should go through code. The point is that even though I've a secured wlan, everyone who comes to my store and has my app to be able to connect to wifi even though it's secured.